# POST cannot read variables sent via url

Tags: php, api, isset

I created a REST API using PHP to receive data from my Android Application using `JsonObjectRequest`. I am testing the API by invoking it using the following url in `Postman`, however my PHP application tells me that it is not receiving the `params`

URL: `http://192.168.2.15/login_api/login.php?email=test@test.com&password=test`

Here is my `login.php`:

```
<?php

require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $user = $db->getUserByEmail($email, $password);

    if ($user != FALSE) {
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
        $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
        $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
        $response["user"]["date_created"] = $user["date_created"];
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "User does not exist!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters are missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}   
?>
```

I always end up getting `Required parameters are missing!`. Can someone help me out with this please?

Comment: In the url you get the variables with ``$_GET[key]``

Comment: `$_REQUEST` also contains both GET and POST variables

Comment: You should not send passwords via GET, as it is highly unsecure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Not **POST**. It's **GET** . I changed your code respective to GET Method.

```
<?php

require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_GET['email']) && isset($_GET['password'])) {
    $email = $_GET['email'];
    $password = $_GET['password'];

    $user = $db->getUserByEmail($email, $password);

    if ($user != FALSE) {
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
        $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
        $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
        $response["user"]["date_created"] = $user["date_created"];
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "User does not exist!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters are missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}   
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! So shouldn't it also be `if (isset($_GET['email']))´ as well?

Comment: Ohh.. I just missed it. Thanks for reminding me @BurninatorDor

Comment: As you have not ticked answer as correct answer. People will start answering as it is unanswered question. So, if you think that your problem is solved. You can tick it as right answer. It will be helpful to other users as well. Thanks @BurninatorDor

Comment: I have not been able to test it yet since I am afk. I will mark it as answered now but then come back to you if I still face any issues. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

All variables in URL like your *http://192.168.2.15/login_api/login.php?email=test@test.com&password=test*  are **GET** parameters

Yoy are sending data by GET method